# init.js:196 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'positions' of null

Tags: modal-dialog

I have a modal which triggers on page load for first time viewers, however, when you hit the close button, the video keeps playing and looking at my error block, this is the only error I get:

init.js:196 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'positions' of null

and here is the lines it is screaming about:

```
function openContent(_target, _direction) {

        if (!isDesktop()) return;

        var _element = document.querySelector(_target);

      $(_target).css(_element.positions).css({
          "z-index": 2
      }).animate(_element.destinations, "easeOutQuint", function () {
          $(_target).addClass('active')
      });
      $('header').animate(_element.headerDestinations, "easeOutQuint");

    }

    function closeContent(_direction) {

      var _target = 'section.active';
      var _element = document.querySelector(_target);

      $(_target).removeClass('active').delay(300).animate(_element.positions, "easeOutQuint", function () {
          $(this).css({
              "z-index": -99999
          })
      });
      $('header').delay(300).animate(_element.headerOrigins, "easeOutQuint");

    }

  function isDesktop() {
      if ($(window).width() >= 768) return true;
      else return false;
     }
```

Here is the specific line in question and in beween the *--><--* is where the inspector is pointing:

```
 $(_target).removeClass('active').delay(300).animate(*-->_element<--*.positions, "easeOutQuint", function () {
```

I am pretty new to JS, so please forgive me.
Thanks

Comment: The `document.querySelector(_target);` returns `null`. Make sure that the element in `_target` exists, and that the selector is correct

Comment: right, Iget that, the rest of the script which references _target is not null, just right here.